# Apply rowTemplate on Kendo grid without overriding current

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, typescript, kendo-grid

I'm using Angular 1.4 typescript, with Kendo (using angular directives).

I'm trying to make a RowTemplate for each row, to change the color based on a property of the item.

I know there are some approaches with jQuery, but I find them very displeasing... If I'm using angular, I would like to reference items with angular.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="resultSubTasksGrid"
     kendo-grid="resultGrid"
     k-options="vm.gridOptions"
     k-columns="vm.columns">
</div>
```

This is my gridOptions:.

```
 gridOptions: kendo.ui.GridOptions = { 
        rowTemplate :  "<tr data- uid='#: uid #' ng-class='sent: item.IsSent'></tr>"
    }
```

My problem comes here: I don't want to override the full row. This approach does so. I have lot of columns, and almost all of them have celltemplates I don't want to lose (but I don't want to have them all in the RowTemplate either).

I would like to know if is it possible to have something like:

```
rowTemplate :  "<tr data- uid='#: uid #' ng-class='sent: item.IsSent'>{{RENDERCONTENT}}</tr>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that by how Kendo it's developed, once you set up a row-template, you need to go all in. There is not such thing as partial template or wrapper.

More information [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/style-rows-cells-based-on-data-item-values).